# ITC.HomePage.news.section Header

Tags: app-store-connect

This morning, I logged into the website: https://itunesconnect.apple.com. After I logged in, the website showed an error message:

> {{ l10n['ITC.HomePage.news.sectionHeader'] }}

Because I can't add images here yet, I put a screenshot of this error at https://twitter.com/wybflb/status/646156502080684032.

What's the reason of this error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Logout -> Clear your cache -> and then try again

Comment: Yes，I user Safari,Chrome,Firefox，the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is apple changed his AppStore Review Guide Line,and the account is new,this is mean I was the first time to login, when I loged in the member center,and agree the new guide line,the problem was fixed.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed another browser the problem solved.
Safari and FireFox have this problem.
Chrome does't